# How do you parent an adult child with a horrible ex?

Tags: adult-child, divorce, holidays

I have a 46-year-old son. I'm 62 and his father and I divorced 12 years ago, after 34 years of marriage. I have no one but my son to spend holidays with. My ex has a huge family and a girlfriend. Yet he only calls my son on holidays to spend time with him and his family.

So my son can't say no to his father. His father knows I'm alone, but he still will do anything to mess with me and hurt me. I'm mad at him and my son. I just need advice on how to cope with this and be at peace.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about parenting, but about issues with your ex-husband.

Comment: Hi, Carol, and welcome to parenting. As it stands, your question is off topic, I'm afraid. You might find a forum more helpful for this kind of situation. If you can edit it to concentrate only on the parenting aspect, please do so, and flag for reopening. As I do with anyone who has reason to be sad, I strongly suggest *practicing gratitude* (easy to google). Giving thanks for what you have may be hard at first, but is attitude-changing, and tends to change many aspects of your life. Please give it a go! :)

Comment: Sorry, but there is nothing I want to change.  Close the question.  Thanks

Comment: Carol, have you considered also consulting friends or a therapist for advice? Or http://www.reddit.com/r/NeedAdvice?

Comment: Find a good church group.  Prince of Peace is your answer.

Answer (score 6):

*That is unfortunately not exactly a parenting situation, but more about you and a bit about your ex. Which means, it will probably be closed.*

From my perspective, it's time *you* grow up and become self-reliant. It is not your son's duty to keep you from feeling lonely at the holidays. And if you are very clingy ("I have no one but my son to spend holidays with."), you are more likely to push your son away, not encourage him to celebrate with you.

What if your son had to move to [random place far away]? Your divorce was 12 years ago, plenty of time to develop a network of friends of your own. In your age bracket, there should be more people without a partner or immediate family nearby. They can either give you hints about how they deal with it or be grateful for your company.

For the holidays, find other lonely people to celebrate with: who says a "family" needs to be related by blood? Be open-minded and open-hearted.

Or volunteer - helping those who have less (both materially and socially) has a way to put our own issues into perspective.

Or simply accept that you are alone - not necessarily a bad thing. Use the day to give yourself a gift, do something you truly enjoy or pamper yourself a bit.

But who says that you can't celebrate with your son at all? Have you considered shifting the dates a bit? Every young couple with two sets of parents has to navigate the murky waters of "who do we celebrate with and when" and while some alternate, many simply celebrate *twice*, e.g. on the weekend before or after the real holiday. If you feel truly hurt, talk to your son and find a solution like that.

From your post, it sounds as if celebrating with your son *and his father* is not an option, but that's something you'll know better than I.

Comment: While I agree with you, I will say *Be Nice*, and that empathy is the better part of valor here. We're not here to point out the OP's failures unless (apparently) they are spanking their children. :-/